# Drawing a Rectangle in Canvas in JavaScript - Defining Rectangle Starting Pont

Tags: javascript, canvas, dimensions

This is my puzzle. I used some code from an online source to draw a rectangle using canvas and have been adjusting it to suit my needs. The original code worked fine, but it's clearly coded to start in the upper left-hand corner of the window; that much I understand from the code. Since my page for it requires it to be relative to the canvas location, not the window, this is a problem for me. When the rectangle is clicked to begin, the actual rectangle starts drawing some distance below the cursor; however further down and to the right the canvas is from (0,0). How do I make it see the canvas as the window to use to define the starting point?

JavaScript:

```
   function getarea() {
         var wid = document.getElementById('wid').value;
         var hgt = document.getElementById('hgt').value;
         var area = (wid*hgt)
         var perim = (+wid + +hgt + +wid + +hgt)
         window.document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = area;
         window.document.getElementById('perim').innerHTML = perim;
      }


var rect;
var canvas;
var context;
var dragging;

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Size(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

function Rectangle(start, size) {
    this.start = start;
    this.size = size;
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDragging, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDragging, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", moved, false);

    var start = new Point(0, 0);
    var size = new Size(0, 0);
    rect = new Rectangle(start, size);


}

function startDragging(event) {
clearRect(rect);
    dragging = true;

    // initialize start point
    var box=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX=box.left;
    var offsetY=box.top;

    var mouseX = parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY);

    rect.start.x = mouseX;
    rect.start.y = mouseY;


    // initialize size
    rect.size.width = 0;
    rect.size.height = 0;
}

function stopDragging(event) {
    dragging = false;
}

function moved(event) {
    if(!dragging) return;

    var box=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX=box.left;
    var offsetY=box.top;

    var mouseX = parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY);

    clearRect(rect);
    rect.size.width = event.pageX - rect.start.x;
    rect.size.height = event.pageY - rect.start.y;
    drawRect(rect);
}

function clearRect(rect) {
    context.clearRect(rect.start.x, rect.start.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}

function drawRect(rect) {
    context.fillRect(rect.start.x, rect.start.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}
```

HTML (normally not as relevant to a JavaScript issue, but I'm including it since the amount of space defined in the HTML is related to the problem. I doubt it's important, but just in case.):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="week5js.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="assignment5.css"/>

<link href="assignment5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</script>

</head>


<header>
<center>
Week 6: Unit 6 - Assignment 5
</center>
</header>


<body onload="init()">

    <form id="areaform">
      <label for="width">Width:</label>
      <input id="wid" name="width" type="number">
      &nbsp
      &nbsp
      <label for="height">Height:</label>
      <input id="hgt" name="height" type="number">
      <br></br>
      <label for="area1">Area:</label>
      <output id="area"></output>
      <br></br>
      <label for="perimeter1">Perimeter:</label>
      <output id="perim"></output>
      <br></br>
      <button onclick="getarea()" type="button">Get Area</button>
    </form>


<canvas id="canvas" width="673" height="550"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
canvas {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid;
}

header{

background-color: yellow;
padding:15px;
margin:30px;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
font-size:25px;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
border: 1px solid;

}

body{
max-width:50%;
padding:25px;
margin:20px;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
font-size:16x;
border: 2px dotted;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #404040;
}

body img{

max-width:100%;

}
```

So, to sum: I need to be able to draw a rectangle from a site, when I do the rectangle starting point is being affected by the canvas' relation to the window and messing everything up and placing the rectangle at a different point than intended. I need the rectangle to start at the cursor.

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than using the `pageX` and `pageY` attributes in your handlers, consider using the `offsetX` and `offsetY` ones. They're relative to the top-left of the _element_ the event handler is attached to, rather than to the whole page itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mouse coordinates which are relative to your canvas:

```
var rect;
var canvas;
var context;
var dragging;

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Size(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

function Rectangle(start, size) {
    this.start = start;
    this.size = size;
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDragging, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDragging, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", moved, false);

    var start = new Point(0, 0);
    var size = new Size(0, 0);
    rect = new Rectangle(start, size);
}

function startDragging(event) {
    dragging = true;

    // initialize start point
    var box=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX=box.left;
    var offsetY=box.top;

    var mouseX = parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY);

    rect.start.x = mouseX;
    rect.start.y = mouseY;

    // initialize size
    rect.size.width = 0;
    rect.size.height = 0;
}

function stopDragging(event) {
    dragging = false;
}

function moved(event) {
    if(!dragging) return;

    var box=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX=box.left;
    var offsetY=box.top;

    var mouseX = parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY);

    clearRect(rect);
    rect.size.width = mouseX - rect.start.x;
    rect.size.height = mouseY - rect.start.y;
    drawRect(rect);
}

function clearRect(rect) {
    context.clearRect(rect.start.x, rect.start.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}

function drawRect(rect) {
    context.fillRect(rect.start.x, rect.start.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! There is one problem with your fix, though. When I start to create the rectangle, it automatically extends the rectangle that original amount horizontally and vertically, so it starts out much larger than intended. Any ideas on how to fix this? :)

Comment: Do you mean the original rectangle remains on the canvas? In that case put `clearRect(rect);` as the first line of your startDragging function. It will clean your canvas.

Comment: that's not what I meant, although that was going to be the next thing I added. :) Basically, previously, when I clicked it started the rectangle further down and to the right the amount described. Now it starts the rectangle at the right point, but automatically starts the rectangle the same height and length difference, so it starts long and slightly wider than intended.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this problem. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome. I'll edit the original post with the entirety of the code I'm now working with, hopefully that helps. :)

Comment: Okay, I also added the CSS, just to make it look entirely correct. Yes, this is part of a homework assignment, but the part that he SUPPOSEDLY gave us the code for. It didn't work for me, so I was trying to recreate it on my own. Thus why I had no qualms about using code I found elsewhere. :)

Comment: That's the entirety of the original code, so you can see what what it was doing before, and relate it to what was happening once your fixes are implemented.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the `moved` function according my solution too? You have to copy moved function from my solution not just startDragging.

Comment: I just edited the first post to show the .js with your changes as I saw them. :) The code that makes the rectangle longer and wider from the beginning. I hope that helps you see what I'm seeing!

Comment: You made mistake in the `moved` function. Instead of these lines     `rect.size.width = event.pageX - rect.start.x;
    rect.size.height = event.pageY - rect.start.y;` use this `     rect.size.width = mouseX - rect.start.x;
        rect.size.height = mouseY - rect.start.y;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to subtract the top left position of the canvas from your position calculation.

Add this global to your set up:

```
var canvasBox = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

If you've wrapped your set up in a function use window.canvasBox instead to make it global.
Then use this function to calculate your new relative position.

```
function getPos(event)
{
    return {"x":event.clientX - canvasBox.left,"y":event.clientY-canvasBox.top};
}
```

Used like so

```
var mousePos = getPos(event);
//mousePos.x
//mousePos.y
```

Here's an extended snippet for working with touches, it has been edited from my library so look out for typos!

```
function init()
{
    window.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    window.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    window.canvasBox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.ontouchstart = function(event){start(event);};
    canvas.ontouchmove = function(event){update(event);};
    canvas.ontouchleave = function(event){end(event);};
    canvas.onmousedown = function(event){start(event);};
    canvas.onmousemove = function(event){update(event);};
    window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event){end(event);},false);
    window.addEventListener('touchend',function(event){end(event);},false);
    window.addEventListener('touchcancel',function(event){end(event);},false);
}

function start(event)
{
    var position = getPos(event);
}
function update(event)
{
    var position = getPos(event);
}
function end(event)
{
    var position = getPos(event);
}

function getPos(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); //stops a touch from scrolling the page etc
    var pos = {};
    if(typeof event.changedTouches !== "undefined") // check for preferred touch data
    {   if(event.changedTouches.length !== 0){ // check to see if there are any touches available
            pos.x = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            pos.y = event.changedTouches[0].clientY;
    }   }
    else if(typeof event.touches !== "undefined") // check for other touch data
    {   if(event.touches.length !== 0){ // check to see if there are any touches available
            pos.x = event.touches[0].clientX;
            pos.y = event.touches[0].clientY;
    }   }
    else if(typeof event.clientX !== "undefined") //check for mouse location
    {
        pos.x = event.clientX;
        pos.y = event.clientY;
    }
    else //set to null as a fallback
    {
        pos.x = null;
        pos.y = null;
    }
    if(pos.x!==null) // if we have a position, make it in canvas relative space
    {
        pos.x -= canvasBox.left; 
        pos.y -= canvasBox.top;
    }
    return pos; 
}
```

Comment: Sure :) Is this code unrelated or in addition to hovitya's code? For some reason on its own I'm having some trouble getting it to work. Perhaps I'm adding them in the wrong location?

Comment: It's basically the same functionality but I thought you'd be able to understand it a little better broken up like this. I made a typo in getPos. Change `function getPos(e)` to `function getPos(event)` will edit in a mo when i've found my touch event version :)

Comment: Hmm...if it's the same functionality, although I'm having trouble locating where exactly these snippets belong (remember, I've been adjusting the code, but the original was from a third party), it might have the same problem that hovitya's did. We're discussing it under his answer. :)

Comment: Well i've added the touch bit but in much more detail, drawing a rectangle from that shouldn't be much more in the way of code... although we're getting pretty far from your example code there :P Would you like a complete solution?

Comment: Oh, dear...putting in the extended version (after looking it over for typos, I didn't find any!) the rectangle won't appear at all. :(

Comment: Ok well don't worry about it, i'll see if i can fit it into your assignment and see if theres any problems :)

Comment: incidentally was the js your using provided/written yourself/taken from another website?? class constructor even basic ones like new being used in there are a little uncommon.

Comment: Yup. I mentioned that in the original post. For this project, we were given the code for this (the actual assignment related to measuring length and width of the resulting rectangle. However, the code was given in a powerpoint and didn't translate properly, thus not working. So I set out to find a base code of my own. That's where this came from. :)

Comment: I'm interested in what would be a more common way of doing this. That would be more useful to learning this material in general. Although I have an answer now, is there a way you could explain this to me a little more, if you're willing? An instant message system or something? (I'm pretty new to this site!)

Comment: There is a chat system, but you need a higher reputation i'm afraid. I have a more basic version pieced together now with touch support which i can talk you through. Got a jsFiddle you can join here http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=f66jcPsmFJ

Comment: I don't really IM anymore...try emailing me :) becats at techie.com.

Comment: (yes, it's a silly email, I got it back in high school. Maaaaany years ago. XD Don't know why I still have it as a backup...)

Comment: ah ok well I'm leaving work in a mo anyway, will email you  before i go :)

Comment: Thanks for that, and thank you for your willingness to help me. HTML and CSS are easy, but JavaScript is thoroughly kicking my butt!